# Cannot use object of type as array on array_push

Tags: php

I am running into an issue trying to push an object into an Array in PHP. My Object looks like the below sample and has 2 empty array's. When i try to use the push_array function i get the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type
>   ResidentialListing as array in /var/www/html/PHRETS/retsphp.php:95

Not sure why as Changes is a Array.

Here is how i call it where $r is an Object but i get same error if i try to push string.

```
array_push($Listing['Changes'], $r);
```

Below is $Listing Object

```
object(ResidentialListing)#86 (5) {
  ["_id"]=>
  string(36) "b77130b6-aea8-4325-9f04-fb77d2cc307f"
  ["_type"]=>
  string(11) "Residential"
  ["Record"]=>
  object(Residential_obj)#110 (18) {
    ["ListingId"]=>
    string(9) "S09100062"
    ["ListingKeyNumeric"]=>
    string(7) "4461874"
    ["StandardStatus"]=>
    string(6) "Closed"
    ["PreviousStandardStatus"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["ParcelNumber"]=>
    string(10) "6051018010"
    ["UniversalPropertyID"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["MLSAreaMajor"]=>
    string(17) "699 - Not Defined"
    ["MajorChangeType"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["Images"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Changes"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: `$Listing` is an object use `$Listing->Changes`.  And better, just do `$Listing->Changes[] = $r;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incorrectly referencing $Listing->Changes as $Listing['Changes'].

It is looking for an array key on an object when you really want the value of the property.

Change

```
array_push($Listing['Changes'], $r);
```

to

```
array_push($Listing->Changes, $r);
```

Comment: I thought ['Changes'] was the correct syntax for accessing Arrays. and ->Changes would be a object. Is this due as the Array is empty ?

Comment: No, its because the you're accessing a property of an object that is an array. If you wanted to access a value of the array changes then your syntax would be $Listing->Changes['key_here'];